# I am not able to add click event for the padding of element in jQuery.

Tags: jquery

i have simple query regarding jquery. 
I have a element that have padding left 10px. i am creating ajax for the click of the element. 
But i have to allow the ajax call on padding of the element also. 
So how can i add click event to the padding of element.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xt9z8L8t/1/ ?

Comment: <pre><code><label class="radio-inline portfolioType">
 <div class="iradio checked">
              <input type="radio" class="port-radio" name="portfolioType" id="inlineRadio2" value="0" checked="checked" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;"></code></pre>
                     <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></ins>
</div> Image        
</label>

Comment: my code is this and i have added click event on label class "radio-inline". it has padding left 10 px. so ajax not work on clicking the padding of label

Comment: Edit the jsfiddle to demonstrate your issue

Comment: Can you alter your HTML? If yes, place a wrapper div around the element and ad ajax call to it